# How should I interperet the Boltzmann distrubution function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

In my physics A-Level course we have been studying the Boltzmann factor

$$N_{i}/N_{j} = e^{-(\epsilon _{i} - \epsilon_{j})/kT}\,,$$

where $N_{i}$ and ${N_{j}}$ are the number of particles with at energy levels with energies $\epsilon _{i}$ and  $\epsilon_{j}$ respectively. I understand how this works for discrete energy distrubutions, but my course (*Advancing Physics, OCR B*) requires me to use this formula without any reference to energy levels. This is best illustrated with an example:

> In a gas of molecules at $2^{\circ}\textrm C$, each of mass $m=5.34 \times 10^{-26}\,\textrm{kg}$, what is the proportion of particles which have a speed $v$ of greater than $500\,\textrm{m/s}$?

The physics department at my school offer two different solutions, (which is unhelpful,) namely to substitute $\epsilon _{i} - \epsilon_{j} = mv^2/2$ into the equation, or to substitute $\epsilon _{i} - \epsilon_{j} = mv^2/2 - kT$. (According to the mark scheme given by one member of the department, the first is correct, but my particular physics teacher suggested the second.)

My first problem with these solutions is that the Boltzmann factor is for the ratio of numbers of particles *on particular energy levels*, but here we are interpreting $N_{i}$ and  $N_{j}$ as the number of particles with energy at least $\epsilon _{i}$ or $\epsilon_{j}$ (*) (or so I believe). Is it valid to apply the formula in this way?

Secondly, the two different solutions. The first has $\epsilon_{j} = 0$, [which makes more sense to me, since it works if you follow the interpretation (*)]. The second one seems to be comparing the populations for the kinetic energy and the average energy (which in my course is always assumed to be $kT$), which I think is still wrong even if we use the interpretation (*).

Most of the problems in this topic are of this form, which I can blindly solve by shoving the most obvious value of $\epsilon _{i} - \epsilon_{j}$ into the formula, but I actually want to understand precisely what this equation is telling me.